# How do i get a value out of an error?

Tags: python, error-handling

I am trying to fix a Text RPG I made and I just need to know how to get a value out of an error.

I need to do this so I can make a system that allows you to put in a string and output some data for the game.

```
if VauleError == True:
    retry()
```

So what I'm using it for is this.

```
while do == "" or do.len(4):                            
    cls()                                                     
    do = input("Data? (Press enter if nothing.)")             
    if do == "":                                              
        while " " in name:                                    
            name = input("Name the hero. ")                   
            if " " in name:                                   
                input("Please don't use spaces")              
                cls()                                         
    else:                                                     
        try:                                                  
            name = str(do.split()[0])                         
            kills = int(do.split()[1])                        
            extra_hp = int(do.split()[2])                     
            extra_dmg = int(do.split()[3])                    
            gold = int(do.split()[4])                         
        except ValueError:                                    
            input("Invalid Save.")                            
            cls()                                             
        else:                                                 
            input("Save Loaded.")
```

I don't know how i would do it. 
The cls() is clear screen.

Comment: `Vaule` > `Value`?

Comment: This may be of interest to you: [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23294658/953482)

Comment: You neednt do the same split 5 times. Just do it once.

Comment: In case you're wondering how to do what Paul Rooney mentioned, 
`do = do.split()` stores the split version in `do`. Or you can use a different variable, your call.

Answer (score 1):

Edited according to comment.

Use a try and except block.

```
user_input = ""
while user_input == ""
    try:
        user_text = input()
        #Code that throws the value error
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid option. Please input...")
        user_text = ""
        #What you want to happen for this specific error
#Continue with program
```

This will make the `user_text` go to `""` again every time the `ValueError` gets thrown, keeping the loop going until ValueError doesn't get thrown.

Comment: Thats what i done but how would i make it to keep doing it over and over again. So if the person is just entering random stuff.

Comment: Put the loop in a function and return when valid, otherwise keep looping

Comment: question scope creep alert. Look at the question comment above to answer your extended query.